# php xml schema formatting

Tags: php, xml

I have a php page what post's a xml to [Heartinternet API](http://api.heartinternet.co.uk/api2.html) and after a long time I have got it to work but now I cant find away to only pull only one part out of the replyed XML

```
$some_xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:package="http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/whapi/package-2.2">
  <command>
    <info>
      <package:info>
        <package:id>171371a16973b1bf</package:id>
      </package:info>
    </info>
    <extension>
      <ext-package:preAuthenticate xmlns:ext-package="http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/whapi/ext-package-2.2"/>
    </extension>
    <clTRID>fac89208bea460fa3fef11b22a519cce</clTRID>
  </command>
</epp>';
```

This is the code what is posted to the API. Full code can been seen [here](https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/log.txt).

This is what I get back and can't figure out how to pull one line from the reply.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:ext-package="http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/whapi/ext-package-2.2">
  <response>
    <result code='1000'>
      <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData>
      <ext-package:redirectURL>http://bobcp.example.org/sso.cgi?session=LUB9UNbw6jTW</ext-package:redirectURL>
    </resData>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>fac89208bea460fa3fef11b22a519cce</clTRID>
      <svTRID>test-19272326601ef4c3bf6b64730d09c6cf</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

The one line I need to show is `ext-package:redirectURL`.

If anyone could help me or point me in the right direction to find **how to sort this** I would be grateful!

Comment: So you run the php from [this file](https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/log.txt) and the `$returned_xml` contains the second xml from your example? Can you show (or the beginning of if it is very long) a `var_dump($returned_xml);`

Comment: this is how to file runs on the server with the code i posted
https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/test.php
as you can see if you refresh this page the url gets changed and i want to show just the url what has been updated

and here is how it runs with the var_dump($returned_xml); in it
https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/test-var_dump.php

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer. The xml on from `https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/test.php` is different than the xml that you posted. (Different in the way where the namespace is added.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the redirect url by registering the namespace `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0` and then you could use an xpath expression for example. In this case, I have chosen `u` as the prefix.

> /u:epp/u:response/u:resData/ext-package:redirectURL

Using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) with your returned xml:

The response xml from the comments is slightly different. This is the updated code:

```
$returned_xml->registerXPathNamespace('u', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0');
$returned_xml->registerXPathNamespace('ext-package', 'http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/whapi/ext-package-2.2');
$redirectUrl = $returned_xml->xpath('/u:epp/u:response/u:resData/ext-package:redirectURL');
echo $redirectUrl[0];
```

Or with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents("https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/test.php"));
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('u', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0');
$xpath->registerNamespace('ext-package', 'http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/whapi/ext-package-2.2');
$redirectUrl = $xpath->query('/u:epp/u:response/u:resData/ext-package:redirectURL')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $redirectUrl;
```

That will give you for example:

`http://bobcp.example.org/sso.cgi?session=LUB9UNbw6jTW`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:ext-package="http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/whapi/ext-package-2.2">
  <response>
    <result code='1000'>
      <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData>
      <ext-package:redirectURL>http://bobcp.example.org/sso.cgi?session=LUB9UNbw6jTW</ext-package:redirectURL>
    </resData>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>fac89208bea460fa3fef11b22a519cce</clTRID>
      <svTRID>test-19272326601ef4c3bf6b64730d09c6cf</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

that is what i get sent back from the API its not in my test page at all

[Full page source](https://custom-hosting.co.uk/source/log.txt)

if i add

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($returned_xml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('u', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0');
$redirectUrl = $xml->xpath('/u:epp/u:response/u:resData/ext-package:redirectURL');
echo $redirectUrl[0];
```

to the page i just get

XML Parsing Error: no element found

Location: https://custom-hosting.co.uk/

Line Number 1, Column 1: